# Why does subprocess.call() not execute scp unless "shell=True" is included?

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess, scp

My program securely copies in this manner: `subprocess.run(scp -P 22 username@address.com:path/to/file $HOME/Downloads)`.

But it gives me the following error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scp -P 22 username@address.com:path/to/file $HOME/Downloads`.

However, adding `shell=True` like so `subprocess.run(scp -P 22 username@address.com:path/to/file $HOME/Downloads, shell=True)` fixes it.

Why is that? Is there a way around it or is `shell=True` essential?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the documentation, you'll see that `subprocess.run` actually wants a list of values, not a single string:

```
subprocess.run( ["scp", "-P", "22", 
    "username@address.com:path/to/file"
    "$HOME/Downloads"] )
```

HOWEVER, there's another issue here.  `$HOME` is a shell variable.  If you don't use `shell=True`, then you need to expand it yourself:

```
subprocess.run( ["scp", "-P", "22", 
    "username@address.com:path/to/file",
    os.environ["HOME"]+"/Downloads"] )
```

You don't need to specify "-P 22".  That's the default port for ssh.

Comment: I can edit my question but originally I did start off by giving it a list of values. The problem was the way I was specifying the path was `~/Downloads/` and that just returned the output for `scp -h` which is about usage. However, using `~/Downloads` to specify path for `scp` in the terminal directly worked just fine. The fact that the same command didn't work in the program was why I was confused.

Comment: RIght.  `~` is also a shell shortcut.  If you aren't invoking a shell, then `~` will not be expanded.  You need to do it yourself.